# PIL and python static typing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, typing

I have a function argument which can accept several types for an image:

```py
def somefunc(img: Union[np.array, Image, Path, str]):
```

The PIL `Image` in this case throws the following exception:

```py
TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got <module 'PIL.Image' from ...
```

Which makes sense after inspecting an image object further:

```py
print(type(Image.open('someimage.tiff')))
>>> <class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile'>
```

How would I go about specifying a generalized type for a PIL image? It being from a file and it's format should be irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like you've imported `Image` incorrectly, and `Image` is referring to a module, not a class within the module.

Comment: The import is correct, hence the part where I print the return type of the Image.open(). I can run .show() on the object and get the image as expected.

Comment: Are you sure? `Got <module 'PIL.Image' ` "Got module", which itself isn't a type. I think you interpreted the error incorrectly.

Comment: Too early in the morning :). I needed to do: from PIl.Image import Image, not from PIL import Image. Thanks @Carcigenicate

Comment: Np, I'm pretty sure I got a similar error when I used PIL last.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't have a IDE handy, but the error you're getting:

```
. . . Got <module 'PIL.Image'
```

Suggests that you're attempting to use the module itself as a type when you mean to refer to the `Image` object contained within the module.

I'm guessing you have an import like

```
from PIL import Image
```

Which makes `Image` refer to the module, not the object.

You want something like

```
from PIL.Image import Image
```

So that the object itself is imported.

Note though, now `Image` refers to the object. You may need to do something like this if you want to refer to both the object and module within the same file:

```
from PIL import Image as img
from PIL.Image import Image
```

Now the module is aliased as `img`.

Comment: This is correct, but so obnoxious.  Everybody says `from PIL.Image import Image` in their code.  If you use `from PIL.Image import Image` then no standard code works - e.g. `Image.open` doesn't work.  So really you should probably use `Image.Image` as the class.  Thanks for the namespace collision, PIL.  :(

Answer (score 7):

Similar to the other answers, you could do `def somefunc(img: Union[np.array, Image.Image, Path, str]):` to call the module's object directly. Tested in python 3.9.

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('some_path.png')
print(type(img))  # <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
def to_gray(img:Image.Image):
    return img.convert("L")
img = to_gray(img)
print(type(img))  # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

The type changes normally with `.convert("L")`

Comment: `Image.Image`: beautiful - thanks!